# Escape "\" character in python string [need to avoid hexa encoding]

Tags: python, regex, forward

Need to pick IP address from this string
    `str1 = '<\11.1.1.1\testdata>'`

When the following option implemented
1. 
    
    `reg = re.compile("^.*\/+([\d\.]+)/\+.*$",re.I).search
    mth = reg(str2)
    mth.group(1)`

Got the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#90>", line 1, in <module>
    mth.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

option 2.

```
str1 = "<\11.1.1.1\cisco>"
str1.replace("\\","\\\\")
print str1

output - '<\t.1.1.1\\\\cisco>'
```

3. Tried making str1 as a raw string

   `str1 = r"<\11.1.1.1\cisco>"
   str2 = str1.replace("\\","/");
   print str2
   output - '</11.1.1.1/cisco>'`

   `reg = re.compile("^.*\/+([\d\.]+)/\+.*$",re.I).search
   mth = reg(str2)
   mth.group(1)`

'

```
error message - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#90>", line 1, in <module>
    mth.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: You tried raw strings... but only on `str1` and not on the regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should raw string form:

```
str1 = r"<\11.1.1.1\cisco>"
print re.search(r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)+\b', str1).group()
11.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = r'<\11.1.1.1\testdata>'
reg = re.compile(r"^.*?\\([\d\.]+)\\.*$",re.I)
mth = reg.search(str1)

print mth.group(1)
```

You need to use `raw` strings at both places.

Output:`11.1.1.1`

If you dont want to use `raw` string for regex you will have to use

```
reg = re.compile("^.*?\\\([\d\.]+)\\\.*$",re.I)
```